# Why Entity Framework provider manifest token does not return?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have seen plenty of titles in SOF as "The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string." which I see in the InnerException. However, Those are about ASP.NET project. In my case I'm using a simple Console Program which has to work but it doesn't! I am using Entity Framework 5 so I did update it few times with different 5.0.0.0 and 5.0.0-rc using PowerShell console but didn't help.

Same code works on a different machine so I'm sure it is caused by EF. Basically, after running code the DB has to get created automatically but it doesn't.

Any hint or suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Amit

[image]

Comment: did you check your connection string...?

Comment: I'm assuming you are talking abut App.config, right? if so, I have not touched anything since the video I am following is showing me how EF works where we do not need to create anything and yet the DB will be created automatically